# Clean way to iterate through a list in pairs in Python?

Tags: python, performance, list, for-loop, split

I am using a `string.split(':')` function so that my list consists of firstname:lastname pairs (e.g. `["John", "Doe", "Alex", "Jacobson" ...]`

I know how to use a basic for loop where I would increment the index by two each time (and compare to the length of the list), but I want to take care of it in a more Python specific way.

Are there any cleaner looping constructs I can take which would allow me to consider the first two indices, and then the next two, etc?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most "pythonic" way to iterate over a list in chunks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks) and [alternative way to split a list into groups of n](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624883/alternative-way-to-split-a-list-into-groups-of-n/1625023) and [how do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

Call `iter` on the list and `zip`:

```
l = ["John", "Doe", "Alex", "Jacobson"]

it = iter(l)

for f,l  in zip(it, it):
    print(f,l)

John Doe
Alex Jacobson
```

`zip(it,it)` just consumes two elements from our iterator each time until the iterator is exhausted so we end up getting the first and last names paired. It is somewhat equivalent to:

```
In [86]: l = ["John", "Doe", "Alex", "Jacobson"]

In [87]: it = iter(l)

In [88]: f,l = next(it),next(it)

In [89]: f,l
Out[89]: ('John', 'Doe')

In [91]: f,l
Out[91]: ('Alex', 'Jacobson')
```

Comment: Which can be generalised to chunks of `n` as [`zip(*[iter(xs)]*n)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16758257/478656)

Answer (score 1):

```
for first,last in zip(string[::2],string[1::2]):
```

should work.

EDIT: sorry, I wasn't really being concise.

What zip does is create an object that allows two variables in a for loop. In this case, we are creating a zip object with a sliced list of every other object starting at index 0 (`string[::2]`) and a sliced list of every other object starting at index 1 (`string[1::2'`). We can then use two iterators (`first,last`) to iterate through that zip list.

ie.

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3,4]
>>> l2= [5,6,7,8]
>>> zip(l1,l2)
<zip object at 0x02241030>
>>> for l,k in zip(l1,l2): print(l+k)
...
6
8
10
12
>>> for l,k in zip(l1,l2): print (l,k)
...
1 5
2 6
3 7
4 8
```

Comment: What is happening here exactly?

Comment: Why should this work? If you have to say (and only say) "this should work"  it's probably a bad answer. Explain yourself

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> L = ["John", "Doe", "Alex", "Jacobson"]
>>> for fname, lname in zip(*itertools.repeat(iter(L), 2)): print(fname, lname)
...
John Doe
Alex Jacobson
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use splicing, ie,
Assuming all the names are in x

```
fname = x[::2]
lname = x[1::2]
y = []
for a,b in zip(fname,lname):
    y.append({'fname':a,
              'lname':b,})
```

Now you can easily iterate by,

```
for i in y:
    print i['fname'], i['lname']
```