# Javascript lo-dash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

How do you take an array and turn it in to this using lo-dash

Takes an array

```
["BBC", "url", false, "Apple", "url", false, "Google", "url", false]
```

outputs:

```
[
   {
      "title" : "BBC", 
      "href" : "url",
      "window_check": false
    },
    {               
       "title" : "Apple", 
       "href" : "url",
       "window_check": false},
    {               
       "title" : "Google", 
       "href" : "url",
       "window_check": false
    },
];
```

Currently I was doing this but failed.

```
var array123 = ["BBC", "url", false, "Apple", "url", false, "Google", "url", false];

_.reduce(array123, function(result, value, key) { result[key]=value; return result;}, {});
```

I got this.

```
{0: "BBC", 1: "url", 2: false, 3: "Apple", 4: "url", 5: false, 6: "Google", 7: "url", 8: false}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there ya go

```
var keys = ['title','href','window_check'];
var out = _.reduce(array123, function(result, value, idx) {
    if (idx % keys.length == 0)
        result.push({});
    result[result.length - 1][keys[idx % keys.length]] = value;
    return result;
},[]);
```

if you want to create new objects for every X items with objects, your logic actually needs to include that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did indeed output the way I needed it to

Comment: would be mighty fine of you if you marked it as the answer. i need at least another 4 points to save an orphan

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use underscore/lodash at all:

```
var result = [];
for (var i=0; i<array123.length; )
    result.push({
        "title": array123[i++],
        "href": array123[i++],
        "window_check": array123[i++]
    });
```

If you want to take a functional approach, define [some `chunkN` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566667/split-javascript-array-in-chunks-using-underscore-js) and then use

```
var result = _.chain(array123).chunkN(3).map(function(chunk) {
    return {
        "title": chunk[0],
        "href": chunk[1],
        "window_check": chunk[2]
    }
}).value();
```

Comment: upvoting for simply stating that this should be done in 'raw' javascript ^_^ and i would add another one if i could for the chunkN function, never knew that one... thanks!