# How to render array into specific form for mustache to render

Tags: javascript, html, underscore.js, mustache

I get an array of objects with image locations via API and I can't manage to render it.

I managed to get my array into chuncks of 4 using underscore, but I can't get my head around how to massage my data into correct form so I could render it out through mustache.

The code currently looks like this:

```
var template = "<ul>{{#images}}<li>{{location}}</li>{{/images}}</ul>";

var data = [
    {"location":"gallery\/Baar_Toit_5.jpg"},
    {"location":"gallery\/Baar_Toit_7.jpg"},
    {"location":"gallery\/Baar_Toit_8.jpg"},
    {"location":"gallery\/Baar_Int_1.jpg"},
    {"location":"gallery\/Baar_Int_2.jpg"},
    {"location":"gallery\/Baar_Int_3.jpg"},
    {"location":"gallery\/Baar_Int_4.jpg"},
    {"location":"gallery\/Baar_Uus_01.jpg"},
    {"location":"gallery\/Baar_Uus_02.jpg"},
    {"location":"gallery\/Baar_Uus_03.jpg"},
    {"location":"gallery\/Baar_Uus_04.jpg"},
    {"location":"gallery\/Baar_Uus_05.jpg"},
    {"location":"gallery\/Baar_Uus_06.jpg"},
    {"location":"gallery\/Baar_Uus_07.jpg"}
];

var n = 4;
var imgs = _.groupBy(data, function(element, index){
    return Math.floor(index/n);
});

console.log(imgs);

Mustache.parse(template);
var rendered = Mustache.render(template, { imgs: JSON.parse(imgs) });
$('#gallery').html(rendered);
```

I created a small sandbox for testing purposes, feel free to play around with it: http://jsfiddle.net/qK5NT/149/

My desired output is:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <p>img/1.jpg</p>
        <p>img/2.jpg</p>
        <p>img/3.jpg</p>
        <p>img/4.jpg</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>img/5.jpg</p>
        <p>img/6.jpg</p>
        <p>img/5.jpg</p>
        <p>img/6.jpg</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>img/5.jpg</p>
        <p>img/6.jpg</p>
        <p>img/5.jpg</p>
        <p>img/6.jpg</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>img/5.jpg</p>
        <p>img/6.jpg</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`groupBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) isn't the right tool for this job, objects aren't ordered in JavaScript so there's no guarantee that you'll get your chunks in the right order. Yes, this means that the [canonical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8566836/479863) for chunking is wrong.

So your first problem is to properly chunk the data. If you're using lodash, you could use its [`_.chunk`](https://lodash.com/docs#chunk). If you're using plain Underscore, you could mixin your own `_.chunk` and the lodash version can be easily adapted:

```
_.mixin({
    chunk: function(a, n) {
        // Based on lodash's
        var i = 0, length = a.length, ri = -1;
        var result = Array(Math.ceil(length / n));
        while(i < length)
            result[++ri] = a.slice(i, i += n);
        return result;
    }
});
```

Now you can chunk your data into fours and get an array-of-arrays out with everything in the right order:

```
var chunks = _(data).chunk(4);
```

Then you want to hand the `chunks` to your template:

```
var rendered = Mustache.render(template, {
    chunks: chunks
});
```

And finally, your template needs to iterate over the chunks to produce the `<li>`s and then iterate over each chunk to produce the `<p>`s inside the `<li>`s. That would look like this:

```
<ul>
    {{#chunks}}
        <li>
            {{#.}}
                <p>{{location}}</p>
            {{/.}}
        </li>
    {{/chunks}}
</ul>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/b2te16pj/

Comment: Except the example calls `.toArray` on the returned object, so you will get back an ordered array.

Comment: @ColinDeClue: But `_.toArray(some_object)` doesn't guarantee that it will sort the `some_object` by its keys, `toArray` will just iterate over the object and give you the values in whatever order `_.each` would use (i.e. no specified order at all). Tacking a `toArray` call onto the `groupBy` doesn't solve the order problem.

Comment: @mu is too short: Thank you for a such a great answer!

Comment: @muistooshort: Ah, I assumed it would go off the keys in the object. But yeah that would only work if the keys were always numbers, which it can't guarantee.

Comment: @ColinDeClue: The keys are **always** strings but it doesn't matter what the keys are because nothing anywhere sorts them. The object's keys are no ordered, `toArray` uses `_.values` and `_.keys` internally (at least the current version does) and neither of those sort the keys (and they'd get it wrong if they did because the keys are strings and `'2'` and `'11'` don't sort like numbers). That other implementation is relying on accidental and unspecified behavior so it is wrong.

Comment: @muistooshort: Interestingly, Chrome sorts object keys numerically. (as in, it would do `1`,`2`,`3`,`11`,`foo`, etc., regardless of insertion order. So it's not accidental behavior, but it is nonguaranteed.

Comment: @ColinDeClue: I think it used to use insertion order. If they've changed then a lot of Backbone events and routing code that depended on the old undocumented behavior is now broken. That would actually be a good illustration of why assuming order in an object is a bad idea :)

Comment: @ColinDeClue: Actually, I think it is still using insertion order combined with some sort of "numbers first" magic (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/1gccpj9L/). This is a nice illustration of the dangers of generalizing from one case or the "just try it and see what happens" school of thought :)