# group by array of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array, which is currently grouped like this:

```
{
  data: [ListingModel, ListingModel, ListingModel, ListingModel, ListingModel, ListingModel]
};
```

I'd like it to be grouped like this:

```
{
  groupedData: [
    [ListingModel, ListingModel],
    [ListingModel, ListingModel],
    [ListingModel, ListingModel]
  ]
};
```

Comment: So you mean to pair them up? Have you tried anything for yourself yet? Please include that

Comment: If lodash will do then check out the [chunk](https://lodash.com/docs#chunk) function

Comment: How are you deciding which objects are together/paired?

Comment: Chunk in underscorejs answered here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566667/split-javascript-array-in-chunks-using-underscore-js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566667/split-javascript-array-in-chunks-using-underscore-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop the input 2 at a time, and create a new array for each pair. This new array then gets added to an overall result array...

```
var groupedData = [];

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=2){
    groupedData.push([data[i], data[i+1]]);
}
```

You may want to add validation in the event you have an odd number of elements.

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/9ygchm3s/), I just used strings in this example for the `ListingModel` as you don't define that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
var group_data = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=2)
{
    var arr = [];
    arr.push(data[i]);
    if ( (i + 1) < data.length)
    {
        arr.push(data[i + 1]);
    }

    group_data.push(arr); //push to main array
}
```

Comment: Could you ask your friends to also upvote my answer please, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question, try this.

```js
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0, len = data.length / 2; i < len; i++) {
      var two = [];
      
        if (data[2 * i]) {
            two.push(data[2 * i])
        }
        if (data[2 * i+1]) {
            two.push(data[2 * i+1])
        }
      result.push(two);
    }
    console.log(result);//output: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]
```

Comment: Don't reference other answers. In this case it kind of makes yours redundant as you are acknowledging that there is already an answer very similar to yours, so why bother posting your answer at all

Comment: Thanks for advice, @musefan. I didn't copy others answer. I tried to find optimum way(faster way).

Answer (score 0):

u see to change associative array from single array

```
var data=['ListingModel', 'ListingModel2', 'ListingModel3',   'ListingModel4',' ListingModel5', 'ListingModel6'];
var new_arr = new Array();
for(var i in data){        
if(i < 3){      
    new_arr[i] = [data[i*2],data[i*2+1]];            
}
}
console.log(new_arr);
```