# Group array values in group of 3 objects in each array using underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Below is an array in which I have to group 3 values in each object:

```js
var xyz = {"name": ["hi","hello","when","test","then","that","now"]};
```

Output should be below array:

```js
[["hi","hello","when"],["test","then","that"],["now"]]
```

Comment: Do a search for chunk. (NB Lodash has a chunk function)

Comment: @user14900042 You've added an extra level of indentation with your edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi please refer this https://plnkr.co/edit/3LBcBoM7UP6BZuOiorKe?p=preview. for refrence [Split javascript array in chunks using underscore.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566667/split-javascript-array-in-chunks-using-underscore-js)

using underscore you can do

**JS**

```
 var data = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8", "a9", "a10", "a11", "a12", "a13"];
var n = 3;
var lists = _.groupBy(data, function(element, index){
  return Math.floor(index/n);
});
lists = _.toArray(lists); //Added this to convert the returned object to an array.
console.log(lists);
```

**or**

Using the chain wrapper method you can combine the two statements as below:

```
var data = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8", "a9", "a10", "a11", "a12", "a13"];
var n = 3;
var lists = _.chain(data).groupBy(function(element, index){
  return Math.floor(index/n);
}).toArray()
.value();
```

Comment: That's looks like the same answer given to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566667/split-javascript-array-in-chunks-using-underscore-js)

Comment: yeah i made reference also

Comment: @gayathri : I want to print that group in following structure . Can you help in that ?
 <ul>
<li><span>a1</span><span>a2</span><span>a3</span></li>
<li><span>a4</span><span>a5</span><span>a6</span></li>
<li><span>a7</span><span>a8</span><span>a9</span></li>
</ul>

Comment: Instead of cutting and pasting the answer to the other question it would be more relevant to change it so that it applied to the data structure in this question.

Answer (score 16):

Pure javascript code:

```
function groupArr(data, n) {
    var group = [];
    for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (i >= n && i % n === 0)
            j++;
        group[j] = group[j] || [];
        group[j].push(data[i])
    }
    return group;
}

groupArr([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], 3);
```

Answer (score 16):

Here's a short and simple solution abusing the fact that `.push` always returns `1` (and `1 == true`):

```js
const arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
const n = 3

arr.reduce((r, e, i) =>
    (i % n ? r[r.length - 1].push(e) : r.push([e])) && r
, []); // => [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]]
```

Plus, this one requires no libraries, in case someone is looking for a one-liner pure-JS solution.

Comment: It's a clever and very useful solution that can be used as an expression and one can even use it to format currency with thousands separators when reversed and r.push([e]) becomes r.push([',',e]) ;)

Comment: Note 0 is a falsy value in JavaScript so this works without a comparison to 0.

Answer (score 7):

This can be covered by lodash [`_.chunk`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#chunk):

```js
var xyz = {"name": ["hi","hello","when","test","then","that","now"]},size = 3;
console.log(_.chunk(xyz.name, size));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: For completeness' sake, this also works with Underscore.

Answer (score 4):

You may use:

```js
function groupBy(arr, n) {
  var group = [];
  for (var i = 0, end = arr.length / n; i < end; ++i)
    group.push(arr.slice(i * n, (i + 1) * n));
  return group;
}

console.log(groupBy([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 3));
```

Comment: modifying the array your just iterating over is one of the oldest anti-patterns in programming....

Comment: What did you smoke @jebbie? I'm not modifying the array I'm iterating over! If you look closer, you'll see that I create a new array and then I add slices of the array passed in argument. `Array.prototype.slice` always returns a new array. IT NEVER MODIFIES IT.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another simple oneliner, quite similar to [the solution of gtournie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51813112).

1. We create an array of the desired length `array.length / n`.
2. We map portions of the initial array to the new array elements.

```js
const group = (array, n) => 
  [...Array(Math.ceil(array.length / n))]
    .map((el, i) => array.slice(i * n, (i + 1) * n));
```

```js
var xyz = {"name": ["hi","hello","when","test","then","that","now"]};
group(xyz.name, 3)
```

gives

```js
[["hi","hello","when"],["test","then","that"],["now"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem and came up with solution using vanilla js and recursion

```
const groupArr = (arr, size) => {
    let testArr = [];
    const createGroup = (arr, size) => {
        // base case
        if (arr.length <= size) {
            testArr.push(arr);
        } else {
            let group = arr.slice(0, size);
            let remainder = arr.slice(size);
            testArr.push(group);
            createGroup(remainder, size);
        }
    }
    createGroup(arr, size);
    return testArr;
}

let data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
console.log(groupArr(data, 3));
>>> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [curry](https://blog.benestudio.co/currying-in-javascript-es6-540d2ad09400)-able version that builds off [Avare Kodcu's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44069560/2559304).

```
function groupBy(groupSize,rtn,item,i)
{
    const j=Math.floor(i/groupSize)

    !rtn[j]?rtn[j]=[item]:
            rtn[j].push(item)

    return rtn
}

arrayOfWords.reduce(curry(groupBy,3),[])
```