# Split jsonarray into chunk arrays into another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs

I am trying to split son array into chunks of 3 inner arrays.

ex:

```
[{
  title: "asd",
  description: "asd"
}, {
  title: "asz",
  description: "sd"
}, {
  title: "ws",
  description: "sd"
}, {
  title: "re",
  description: "sd"
}, {
  title: "32",
  description: "xxs"
}, {
  title: "xxc",
  description: "11"
}]
```

I want to convert upper son array into chunks like below

```
[
  [{
    title: "asd",
    description: "asd"
  }, {
    title: "asz",
    description: "sd"
  }, {
    title: "ws",
    description: "sd"
  }],
  [{
    title: "re",
    description: "sd"
  }, {
    title: "32",
    description: "xxs"
  }, {
    title: "xxc",
    description: "11"
  }]
]
```

I tried some sample like this but its working for this array `['a','b','c','d','e']` fine. below is the code I tried,

```
perChunk = 2 // items per chunk    

inputArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

inputArray.reduce((resultArray, item, index) => {
  const chunkIndex = Math.floor(index / perChunk)

  if (!resultArray[chunkIndex]) {
    resultArray[chunkIndex] = [] // start a new chunk
  }

  resultArray[chunkIndex].push(item)

  console.log(resultArray)
  return resultArray

}, [])
```

But, for my input it's not working.

Please suggest me how can I achieve this

Comment: Your `perChunk` is `2`, yet the example clearly has `3` objects in each...? Also, this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44069560/519413

Comment: The code you tried works for me, except that it splits into chunks with 2 items each instead of chunks with 3, because of your `perChunk = 2`.

Comment: What's your `expected output` when handling `leftover elements`? ie `array.length = 10` but `chunk size = 8` therefore `leftover elements = 2`

Comment: I've added an update to my answer with usage of filter to remove empty objects from the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the array into chunks of required size:

```js
var arr = [{
  title: "asd",
  description: "asd"
}, {
  title: "asz",
  description: "sd"
}, {
  title: "ws",
  description: "sd"
}, {
  title: "re",
  description: "sd"
}, {
  title: "32",
  description: "xxs"
}, {
  title: "xxc",
  description: "11"
}]

var i, j, resArray=[], chunk = 2;
for (i = 0, j = arr.length; i < j; i += chunk) {
  resArray.push(arr.slice(i, i + chunk));
}

console.log(resArray);
```

Comment: Worked great for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can split array into given number of chunks

```
split(arr, n) {
        var res = [];
        while (arr.length) {
            res.push(arr.splice(0, n));
        }
        return res;
    }
```

**Usage**

```
 var arrayFregments = split(myArray, 3); //no of chunks
 var requests = arrayFregments.reduce((promiseChain, item) => {
            return promiseChain.then(() => new Promise((resolve) => {
                 asyncFunction(item, resolve); //some async function
            }));
        }, Promise.resolve());

 requests.then(() => {
               // after requests has been completed.
            });
```

**Update**

If you want to eliminate empty data object then you can use filter

```
mainList = mainList.filter(function(item){
        return item.title.trim().length>0 && item.description.trim().length>0

});
console.log(mainList)
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/zj1pe7q3/3/

Comment: Thanks.. but I can't accept all the answers .. so I am really sorry

Comment: @Basha, Nobody can't ;)

Comment: Hi @Manoj small suggestion, how can I delete elements from array if element values have empty like  title:"" and description:""... ex:[[{title:"a",desc:"ten"},{"title:"",desc:""}]]. here I want output as [[{title:"a",desc:"ten"]] .. any suggestion please

Comment: you can filter array before processing into chunks. See here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp

Comment: but, checking inner key value is possible in this mentioned w3schools url

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mehbub/zj1pe7q3/2/ have a look in the fiddle and the last array element have empty title and empty description. I want to remove those before chunking

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zj1pe7q3/3/ have a look at this, this is what I was talking about

Answer (score 2):

The following snippet `splits` `arrays` into `chunks` by `size`.

[`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is used to `omit` unwanted `elements` (`even numbers`) from the `input` `array`.

[`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and a [`for statement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) are combined to create `chunks` without `mutating` the original `input` `array`.

`Leftovers` are included as a final `chunk` in the `output`, when relevant.

```js
// Input.
const input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].filter(x => x % 2)

// Chunk.
const chunk = (array, size) => {
  let output = []
  let i = 0
  const max = array.length + (array.length % size) + 1
  for (let j = size; j < max; j += size) {
    output.push(array.slice(i, j))
    i = j
  }
  return output
}

// Output / Proof.
console.log('chunk size: 1', chunk(input, 1))
console.log('chunk size: 3', chunk(input, 3))
console.log('chunk size: 5', chunk(input, 5))
```

Comment: Thanks I can't accept answer because I accepted some other one answer

Comment: need small suggestion, jsfiddle.net/mehbub/zj1pe7q3/2 have a look in the fiddle and the last array element have empty title and empty description. I want to remove those before chunking

Comment: [`.filter(({title, description}) => title && description)`](http://jsfiddle.net/ebpow1eo/)  @Basha

Comment: ^ See [`Destructuring Assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [`Short-Circuit Evaluation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Chunk a single array into multiple arrays, each containing `count` or fewer
  // items.
function chunk(array, count) {
    if (count == null || count < 1) return [];
    var result = [];
    var i = 0, length = array.length;
    while (i < length) {
      result.push(Array.prototype.slice.call(array, i, i += count));
    }
    return result;
  };
```

Usage:

```
var newList = chunk(mainList, 2);
```

<kbd>[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zj1pe7q3/)</kbd>

---

OR

You can use [chunk](http://underscorejs.org/#chunk) of underscore or [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#chunk)

```
var mainList = [
  {
    "title": "asd",
    "description": "asd"
  },
  {
    "title": "asz",
    "description": "sd"
  },
  {
    "title": "ws",
    "description": "sd"
  },
  {
    "title": "re",
    "description": "sd"
  },
  {
    "title": "32",
    "description": "xxs"
  },
  {
    "title": "xxc",
    "description": "11"
  }
];

var newList = _.chunk(mainList, 2);
```

Output:

```
[
  [
    {
      "title": "asd",
      "description": "asd"
    },
    {
      "title": "asz",
      "description": "sd"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "title": "ws",
      "description": "sd"
    },
    {
      "title": "re",
      "description": "sd"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "title": "32",
      "description": "xxs"
    },
    {
      "title": "xxc",
      "description": "11"
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: Thanks.. but I can't accept all the answers .. so I am really sorry

Comment: @Basha no worries mate :)

Comment: how can I delete elements from array if element values have empty like  title:"" and description:""... ex:[[{title:"a",desc:"ten"},{"title:"",desc:""}]]. here I want output as [[{title:"a",desc:"ten"]] .. any suggestion please

Comment: @Basha but u still want to make chunks of 2?

Comment: I got splitting into chunks. but, while saving I am saving as 3 chunks ... but throwing error because value is empty. So need to delete the array elements, if the title is empty

Comment: Please take my demo in fiddle and reproduce your case there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172049/discussion-between-basha-and-maxim-shoustin).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that:

```
const chucnk = (array, chunckSize) =>
  array.reduce(
    (a, b, i, g) =>
      !(i % chunckSize) ? a.concat([g.slice(i, i + chunckSize)]) : a,
    []
  );

const array = [{
  title: "asd",
  description: "asd"
}, {
  title: "asz",
  description: "sd"
}, {
  title: "ws",
  description: "sd"
}, {
  title: "re",
  description: "sd"
}, {
  title: "32",
  description: "xxs"
}, {
  title: "xxc",
  description: "11"
}]

chunck(array,3);
```

Comment: Thanks.. but I can't accept all the answers .. so I am really sorry